# grand totals line not displaying data in COBOL

Tags: cobol

After creating the complete template for this batch program, which takes input from a txt file and outputs your configurations, it will add up points earned and display them, and it will add up points possible and points earned columns, and display them, both at the bottom of each list, One for assignments, and one for tests, THEN finally it will display a grand totals line at the VERY bottom of the file. Currently, the template is configured, now all we need are the grand total percent, and letter grade, all of which are NOT showing up in the output file, this is what I need help figuring out.

The attached image is the desired output for the program. [[image: desired output for program]]

The .SEQ file, listed below, MUST be copy and pasted into the bin/ debug folder in your project folder, if you are using visual studio I assume it will be the same throughout. At my school we use Visual Studio 2015, so not sure how it will translate over. You can save this info in notepad.

```
Assignment #1  010 010
Assignment #2  028 030
Assignment #3  045 050
Assignment #4  109 130
Assignment #5  095 100
Assignment #6  000 000
Assignment #7  000 000
Assignment #8  000 000
Assignment #9  000 000
Assignment #10 000 000
Test #1        009 012
Test #2        018 018
Test #3        028 037
Test #4        019 025
Test #5        043 055
Test #6        015 023
Test #7        000 000
Test #8        000 000
Test #9        000 000
```

Listed below is the actual program itself.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. GRADES.
      * BOB
      ******************************************************************
      *    THIS PROGRAM WILL ADD UP ASSIGNMENTS AND TESTS COLUMNS
      *    AND DISPLAY TOTALS FOR EACH THEN PRESENT A FINAL TOTAL
      *    LINE THAT DISPLAYS GRAND TOTALS, PERCENTAGE AND THE STU 
      *    DENTS LETTER GRADE
      *    
      ******************************************************************
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
     
           SELECT GRADES-FILE-IN
               ASSIGN TO 'GRADES.SEQ'
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
     
           SELECT GRADES-FILE-OUT
               ASSIGN TO 'GRADES.RPT'
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
     
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
     
       FD  GRADES-FILE-IN.
       01  GRADES-RECORD-IN.
           05  DESCRIPTION-IN          PIC X(14).
           05                          PIC X.
           05  POINTS-EARNED           PIC 999.
           05                          PIC X.
           05  POINTS-POSSIBLE         PIC 999.
     

       FD  GRADES-FILE-OUT.
       01  GRADES-RECORD-OUT           PIC X(80).
     

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS      PIC XXX     VALUE 'YES'.
       01  LINES-PRINTED               PIC 99      VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-POINTS-EARNED            PIC 999     VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE          PIC 999     VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED    PIC .99     VALUE ZERO.
       01  WS-LETTER-GRADE             PIC XX.
       01  WS-GET-GRADE                PIC 99.
       
       
       01  DETAIL-LINE.
           05  DL-DESCRIPTION-IN              PIC X(14).
           05                          PIC X(8)   VALUE SPACES.
           05  DL-POINTS-EARNED        PIC ZZ9.
           05                          PIC X(8)   VALUE SPACES.
           05  DL-POINTS-POSSIBLE     PIC ZZ9.
           
       01 ASG-TOTAL-LINES.
           05                          PIC X(6)   VALUE 'Totals'.
           05                          PIC X(16)  VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-ASG-POINTS-EARNED            PIC ZZ9.
           05                          PIC X(8)   VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-ASG-POINTS-POSSIBLE  PIC ZZ9.
           05                          PIC X(4)   VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(9)   VALUE 'Percent ='.
           05                          PIC XX     VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-ASG-PERCENT          PIC .99.
           05                          PIC XX     VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(7)   VALUE 'Grade ='.
           05                          PIC X      VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-ASG-LETTER-GRADE     PIC X.
           
       01 TEST-TOTAL-LINES.
           05                          PIC X(6)   VALUE 'Totals'.
           05                          PIC X(16)  VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-TEST-POINTS-EARNED           PIC ZZ9.
           05                          PIC X(8)   VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-TEST-POINTS-POSSIBLE PIC ZZ9.
           05                          PIC X(4)   VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(9)   VALUE 'Percent ='.
           05                          PIC XX     VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-TEST-PERCENT         PIC .99.
           05                          PIC XX     VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(7)   VALUE 'Grade ='.
           05                          PIC X      VALUE SPACES.
           05  TL-TEST-LETTER-GRADE    PIC X.
       
       01 FINAL-LINE.
           05                          PIC X(11)  VALUE 'Final Grade'.
           05                          PIC X(29)  VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(9)   VALUE 'Percent ='.
           05                          PIC XX.
           05  FL-PERCENT              PIC .99.
           05                          PIC XX     VALUE SPACES.
           05                          PIC X(7)   VALUE 'Grade ='.
           05                          PIC XX     VALUE SPACES.
           05  FL-LETTER-GRADE         PIC X.
     

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       0100-MAIN.
           OPEN INPUT GRADES-FILE-IN
           OPEN OUTPUT GRADES-FILE-OUT
     
           PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO '
               READ GRADES-FILE-IN
                   AT END
                       PERFORM 0400-WRITE-TEST-TOTALS
                       PERFORM 0600-WRITE-FINAL-GRADE
                       MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
                   NOT AT END
                       PERFORM 0200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD 
               END-READ
           END-PERFORM
     
           CLOSE GRADES-FILE-IN
           CLOSE GRADES-FILE-OUT
           STOP RUN.
    

       0200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD.
           COMPUTE WS-POINTS-EARNED = WS-POINTS-EARNED + POINTS-EARNED
           COMPUTE WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE = WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE + POINTS-POSSIBLE
           COMPUTE WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED
           / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE                                        
           
           PERFORM 0500-GET-LETTER-GRADE
           
           IF DESCRIPTION-IN = 'Test #1' 
               MOVE WS-POINTS-EARNED TO TL-ASG-POINTS-EARNED
               MOVE WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE TO TL-ASG-POINTS-POSSIBLE
               MOVE WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED TO TL-ASG-PERCENT
               MOVE WS-LETTER-GRADE TO TL-ASG-LETTER-GRADE
               PERFORM 0300-WRITE-ASG-TOTALS 
           END-IF
           
           IF DESCRIPTION-IN = ''
               MOVE WS-POINTS-EARNED TO TL-ASG-POINTS-EARNED
               MOVE WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE TO TL-ASG-POINTS-POSSIBLE
               MOVE WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED TO TL-ASG-PERCENT
               MOVE WS-LETTER-GRADE TO TL-ASG-LETTER-GRADE
               PERFORM 0400-WRITE-TEST-TOTALS 
           END-IF
           
           MOVE SPACES TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT DETAIL-LINE
           MOVE DESCRIPTION-IN TO DL-DESCRIPTION-IN
           MOVE POINTS-EARNED TO DL-POINTS-EARNED
           MOVE POINTS-POSSIBLE TO DL-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT
           WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT
               AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINES.
           ADD 2 TO LINES-PRINTED.
           

       0300-WRITE-ASG-TOTALS.
          MOVE WS-POINTS-EARNED TO TL-ASG-POINTS-EARNED
          MOVE WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE TO TL-ASG-POINTS-POSSIBLE
          MOVE WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED TO TL-ASG-PERCENT
          MOVE WS-LETTER-GRADE TO TL-ASG-LETTER-GRADE
          
          MOVE ASG-TOTAL-LINES TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT 
          WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES.
          MOVE SPACES TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT.
          WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
          
          MOVE ZERO TO WS-POINTS-EARNED
          MOVE ZERO TO WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
          MOVE ZERO TO WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED.
          
       
       0400-WRITE-TEST-TOTALS.
          MOVE WS-POINTS-EARNED TO TL-TEST-POINTS-EARNED
          MOVE WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE TO TL-TEST-POINTS-POSSIBLE
          MOVE WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED TO TL-TEST-PERCENT
          MOVE WS-LETTER-GRADE TO TL-TEST-LETTER-GRADE
          
          MOVE TEST-TOTAL-LINES TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT 
          WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES.
          MOVE SPACES TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT.
          WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.
          
          MOVE ZERO TO WS-POINTS-EARNED
          MOVE ZERO TO WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
          MOVE ZERO TO WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED.
       
       
       0500-GET-LETTER-GRADE.
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED
       >= .95 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED < 1
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE 
           MOVE 'A' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED
       >= .90 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED <= .94
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'A-' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED >= .87 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED
       <= .89
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'B+' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED >= .83 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED
       <= .86
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'B' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED >= .80 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED
       <= .82
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'B-' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED >= .77 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED
       <= .79
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'C+' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED >= .74 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED <= .76
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'C' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED >= .70 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED <= .73
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'C-' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED >= .67 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED <= .69
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'D+' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED >= .60 AND WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED <= .66
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'D-' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF
       IF WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED <= .59
           COMPUTE WS-GET-GRADE ROUNDED = WS-POINTS-EARNED / WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE
           MOVE 'E' TO WS-LETTER-GRADE
       END-IF.
         
         
       0600-WRITE-FINAL-GRADE.
           
           MOVE FINAL-LINE TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT
           WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT
               AFTER ADVANCING 2
           ADD 2 TO LINES-PRINTED.
```

Listed below is my output, where you can see missing grand totals and correct letter grading.

```
Assignment #1          10         10
Assignment #2          28         30
Assignment #3          45         50
Assignment #4         109        130
Assignment #5          95        100
Assignment #6           0          0
Assignment #7           0          0
Assignment #8           0          0
Assignment #9           0          0
Assignment #10          0          0

Totals                296        332    Percent =  .89  Grade = E

Test #1                 9         12
Test #2                18         18
Test #3                28         37
Test #4                19         25
Test #5                43         55
Test #6                15         23
Test #7                 0          0
Test #8                 0          0
Test #9                 0          0

Totals                123        158    Percent =  .78  Grade = E


Final Grade                             Percent =       Grade =
```

I have created the desired template for the totals to be displayed, and the computations for said sums.

Comment: You have not submitted batch file code, or explained how a batch file may be relevant to your submission. I have therefore removed your [[tag:batch-file]] tag.

Comment: yes this is batch programming, the batch file is listed at the very beginning.

Comment: You have submitted an SEQ file, the program, and the output, there is absolutely no batch file shown in your question body. Have you clicked on the [batch file tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file), to see its summary description, or read its [tag information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info)?

Answer (score 1):

First, please add `WS-GT-POINTS-EARNED`and `WS-GT-POINTS-POSSIBLE` to your WS, each with a `PIC 9(03)` and value `ZERO`. "GT" here means "Grand Total".

Next, in `0200-`, what you need to do is:

```
Test whether you have arrived at `TEST #1`
If so, produce a totals-report line (0400-)
THEN add the line data to `WS-POINTS-EARNED`and `WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE`
and produce your DETAIL-LINE
```

Your current code adds the `test #1` data (9,12) into `WS-POINTS-EARNED`and `WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE` before printing the totals line. That's why your totals line has 296 instead of 287 and 332 instead of 320. You don't need to calculate the PERCENT-POINTS for each line, that should be done when you produce your totals-report line.

You don't need to test for description-in being empty. Chances are this is a completely incorrect test. Your second total line is being produced by the perform 0400- in the `at end`.

Within 0400-, you should

```
Compute WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED
perform 0500-
move the fields to total-line & print
accumulate `WS-POINTS-EARNED`and `WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE` into `WS-GT-POINTS-EARNED`and `WS-GT-POINTS-POSSIBLE`
zero out `WS-POINTS-EARNED`and `WS-POINTS-POSSIBLE`
```

Note that `0300-` and `ASG-TOTAL-LINES` are now redundant, and `TEST-TOTAL-LINES` can be logically renamed `total-line`.

Within 0500-, you are assigning sometimes 1, sometimes 2 characters to `WS-LETTER-GRADE`. I would suggest adding a space appropriately to make each assignment of 2 characters. Also, since `WS-LETTER-GRADE` is an X(02), so should be `TL-LETTER-GRADE` and `FL-LETTER-GRADE`

Finally, following the bouncing ball, in 0600- you need to

```
Compute WS-PERCENT-POINTS-EARNED from `WS-GT-POINTS-EARNED`and `WS-GT-POINTS-POSSIBLE`
perform 0500-
move the fields to final-line & print
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at COBOL in about forty years, but I can still read it.
The solution would be something like this:

Define fields WS-TOTAL-POINTS-EARNED and WS-TOTAL-POINTS-POSSIBLE

For each record, add the earned points and possible points to these two fields.

In WRITE-FINAL-GRADE,  compute the percentage of total points earned over total points possible and move the result to FL-PERCENT.  Then you will need to PERFORM 0500-GET-LETTER-GRADE and then move WS-LETTER-GRADE to FL-GRADE.

I hope this helps.  I don't know if stackoverflow is meant to be used for homework help but I don't mind.

Of course it is very surprising to find someone learning COBOL today.  It's a terrible language, by modern standards.